# Как сделать,чтобы при адаптивном дизайне,только на телефонах и планшетах изменялось все?А на десктопах нет?

Tags: html, css, responsive, design

Вот но при прохождении брейкпоинта,пропадает навигация даже на ноутбуках,как сделать чтобы только на мобильных она пропадала,а на десктопах,просто сжималась и все?

```
 @media only all and (max-width: 720px) {
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Определять тип устройства через user-agent.